# Executing an EXE file using a PowerShell script with arguments for GCDS

Tags: windows, powershell, google-workspace

I am new to windows and PowerShell on the admin level. I have experience in Linux and prefer using Python but I have a difficult time understanding windows environments. In bash and Linux I am used to running shell scripting with cronjobs but in Windows, I'm having an issue running this command in the Task Scheduler. I need to be able to run Google Cloud Directory Sync so that our AD is in sync with Gsuite. I wrote a batch file that works but I feel its a bit dated to use a bat file

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\
sync-cmd.exe -a -o -c config.xml
```

my best guess is this needs to run as a PowerShell script through task scheduler, but I don't know where to start. I found this so far but I get an error that I don't know how to interpret.

```
Start-Process sync-cmd.exe -ArguementList "-a -o -c C:\Somepath\config.xml"
```

sorry for being a noob thanks in advance!
Also for an additional resource here's the GCDS command page.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6152425?hl=en

Comment: What's the error you don't know how to interpret.

Comment: Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ArguementList'.
At line:1 char:42
+ Start-Process sync-cmd.exe -ArguementList <<<<  "-a -o -c C:\Users\svc_google\C:\Program Files\Google A
Sync\config.xml"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 - Schedule your EXE directly through Task Scheduler**

No need for powershell.  You can just provide the full path to the EXE and the arguments using the Windows Task Scheduler User Interface. You can specify a working folder using the **Start in** option.

**Option 2 - Schedule a PowerShell script using Task Scheduler**

I find using the **-File** option of **PowerShell.exe** very useful when scheduling a PowerShell script using Task Scheduler. In this case, I would use the cmdlet **Start-Process** and I would encapsulate the arguments inside the PowerShell script.

**Example**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "c:\MyScript.ps1"
```

**MSDN**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6

**Syntax**

```
PowerShell[.exe]
       [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                     | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
       [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
       [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
       [-File <FilePath> [<Args>]]
       [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
       [-Mta]
       [-NoExit]
       [-NoLogo]
       [-NonInteractive]
       [-NoProfile]
       [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
       [-PSConsoleFile <FilePath> | -Version <PowerShell version>]
       [-Sta]
       [-WindowStyle <style>]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?
```

**Example from my laptop**

[image]

**Passing arguments through Start-Process**

If you are using Start-Process then you can pass an array of arguments through a comma delimited string.

```
PS C:\> Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c dir `"%systemdrive%\program files`""
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

Comment: This is really helpful thank you! However, I'm still a bit confused because of my shell background.
for example:

in CMD
C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync> sync-cmd.exe -a -o -c config.xml
works for me but I still don't understand how to transfer that to a more scalable design in PowerShell or Task Scheduler.

Comment: You can write a wrapper script *Example.ps1*. Launch your *sync-cmd.exe* from *Example.ps1* using the *start-process* cmdlet.  Schedule *Example.ps1* through Windows  *Task Scheduler.*  Does this help?  When you schedule a Powershell script, you will need to specify the full path to the PowerShell.exe which is is usually found in %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1\

Answer (score 3):

Your error indicates that `Start-Process` does not have a parameter called `ArguementList`. You can use `Get-Help` to get a list of available parameters.

```
Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter * | Select-Object Name
```

Indeed `ArguementList` is not available, but `ArgumentList` is available. There simply is a typo in your command.

The following should work just fine:

```
Start-Process sync-cmd.exe -ArgumentList "-a -o -c C:\Somepath\config.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that PowerShell is pretty similar to python and bash with variables. This runs as a script that I then attach to Task Scheduler.

```
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\sync-cmd.exe"
$arguments = "-a -o -c config.xml"
start-Process -FilePath $msbuild $arguments
```

Comment: You don't have to use variables here. You simply bypass your misspelling by making use of "positional parameters". `Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter ArgumentList` shows you, that this particular parameter is expected in position 1 (or at any position as "named paramter").